# Complete checkout for all orders Drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I am working with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Commerce Billy](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy) to generate invoices. My question is :

In *Complete checkout process* I want to edit all *orders status* to 
"**Invoiced**" !! .

I already created this Rules Component and it works fine. With component I can add 1 order for me(admin) and other orders to user concerned , is that make sense.

So what I want to do is : after complete checkout process I want to change all these orders status to "**invoiced**"

```
{ "rules_add_prod_to_cart_6" : {
"LABEL" : "Add Prod to cart 6",
"PLUGIN" : "rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_cart" ],
"USES VARIABLES" : { "commerce_product" : { "label" : "Commerce Product", "type" : "commerce_product" } },
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-product" ], "field" : "field_user_concerned" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : {
      "USING" : {
        "user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
        "sku" : "[commerce-product:sku]\t",
        "quantity" : "1",
        "combine" : "1"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item" : "Added product line item" } }
    }
  },
  { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : {
      "USING" : {
        "user" : [ "commerce-product:field-user-concerned" ],
        "sku" : "[commerce-product:sku]\t",
        "quantity" : "1",
        "combine" : "1"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item2" : "Added product line item 2" } }
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Example : 
**SKU** | **Label** | **Price** | **User** |

001 | Product 1 | $10 | Userexample1 |
002 | Product 2 | $40 | Userexample2 |
003 | Product 3 | $20 | Userexample1 |
004 | Product 4 | $70 | Userexample2 |

*what I already done:*

So after Clicking on "Add product and generate order" button :
In the above example I get 3 orders
*the owner of the first order = **[site:current-user]** and it will return :*
**All Products** (Product1,Product2,Product3,Product4)
The owner of the second order =  **Userexample1** and it will contain 
Product1 and Product 3 
The owner of the last order = **Userexample2** and it  it will contain 
Product2 and product 4

So the order status of all those orders = Shopping cart (because we didn't complete the checkout yet), and when we complete the checkout it will change ONLY the FIRST ORDER status to **"Invoiced"**, because [site:current-user] is the owner of it.

I want to change all the above orders status when "Complete checkout process" event is fired !

Please see images below:

After Clicking on "Add products to cart and generate orders"
[image]

"New 3 orders"
[image]

Complete checkout process 
[image]

**First order status = Invoiced , BUT THE TWO OTHERS DOSEN'T CHANGE** 
[image]

Is that possible ? How could I do that using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Module ?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens , Thanks for your answer , it's a drupal 7

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Oh sorry it was my fault , I am a new member here , and I really not sure how things work here , anyway thanks !

Comment: No need for sorry, and merci for accepting my advice (and the update of your question). Yes it's not obvious to get used to the [Rrrrrrrules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) of this site (getting started with Drupal may seem easier ...).

Comment: Thanks , Do you have any idea about " How could I do that using Rules module to change all orders status to "Invoiced" when "Complete checkout process" event is fired ?

Comment: I don't know (yet) ... Part of the reason is that I don't understand the question (yet). Please EDIT your question about all this: (1) "***My question is ...***" (you only say what you want, not what your question is) (2) Add more details about what that exported rule is doing (a) what's that Rules Condition (b) what are those 2 Rules Actions actually doing (and why do you have 2 actions that look very similar) (3) what do you mean exactly by that "edit all orders status to invoiced", ie which "orders status" do you mean, those in your rules actions or something else? Sorry for being confused!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53951/discussion-between-media-web-and-pierre-vriens).

Comment: I don't "like" chat ... you cannot "delete" anything in there anymore, and I've trouble using its UI. Can you please try to EDIT your question to further improve it (ie to make me less confused)?

Comment: Oh I am really sorry , I just seen that above the comment box lol . Thanks for telling me that , you are always helpful . you makes me love this site

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, Question edited. I hope you could understand what I was asking for , Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding this PHP code:

`$orders = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('status'=>'cart'), TRUE);
foreach($orders as $order){
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    foreach($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper){
        $product = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product;
        $node_product = $node_wrapper->field_product;
            $order_wrapper->status = 'invoiced';
            $line_item_wrapper->save();
            $order_wrapper->save();
    }
}`